# How do I make a new class whose name is gathered from user input?

Tags: c#, class, input, runtime

I want to create a new instance of a class but I want the name of the instance to be the name inputted by the user whilst the program is running. I don't want Employee employee = new Employee();. I want it to be named according to what the user inputs.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee name");
       string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
       Employee [ inputName ] = new Employee();
```

e.g. If 'inputName' was 'Kaylee' then how do I create an instance whilst the program is running of Employee Kaylee = new Employee();

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: A variable name is not "the name of the instance". It's a variable name and you write that when you write the code. Why would it matter to the user what the variable was called? If you actually want a dedicated link between a `string` and an object then, assuming that the object doesn't have a property you can assign the `string` to, use a `Dictionary`. Make the keys the `strings` and the values the objects.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Variable names are a compile-time issue and have no relevance for run-time.

Comment: You almost certainly want a dictionary.

Comment: Strap in for a Matrix moment: "there is no variable name". Those names are only for us stupid humans with our restricted thinking capacities. After the compiler had its way with the code, that name is probably gone. If you want a user-defined identifier for the instance, that's another story. But note that you might need to make sure it's unique.

Comment: This seems an odd request. Assuming 2 people could have the same name, this doesn't seem a good way to guarantee uniqueness. If you have 2 or more people with the same name, how do you decide which one to carry out the action on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others were pointing out in the comments, dynamically defining a variable name is not possible!

If you want your Employee class to be associated to a name that was input by a user, you have two options in my opinion:

1. Give your Employee class a "Name" property

   ```
   public class Employee
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   That way you can do something like this:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee name");
   string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
   EmployeeList.Add(new Employee{ Name = inputName });
   ```
2. Use a dictionary

   ```
   Dictionary<string, Employee> employees = new Dictionary<string, Employee>();
   Console.WriteLine("Enter Employee name");
   string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
   // Check if employee already exists, since dictionary keys have to be unique
   if(!employees.ContainsKey(inputName))
   {
       employees.Add(inputName, new Employee());
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this solves the OPs question they're asking about, but there's an implied need for uniqueness, hence the suggestions of using a dictionary. However, if the user can legitimately input 2 employees with the same name it will cause issues. It might be better to allow the user to enter a name, but to create a unique id (either in the dictionary or as a prop on the class) and return that to the user instead.